# Delete rows that exist in another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, delete-row, corresponding-records

I have the two following data frames (example):

df1:

```
name    profile    type    strand
A       4.5        1       +
B       3.2        1       +
C       5.5        1       +
D       14.0       1       -
E       45.1       1       -
F       32.8       1       -
G       19.9       1       +
```

df2:

```
name
A
B
C
G
```

I would like to delete the rows in `df1` for which `df1$name = df2$name` to get the following:

Output:

```
name    profile    type    strand
D       14.0       1       -
E       45.1       1       -
F       32.8       1       -
```

If anyone could tell me which piece of code to use it would be a lot of help, seemed simple at first but I've been messing it up since yesterday.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You need the `%in%` operator. So,

```
df1[!(df1$name %in% df2$name),]
```

should give you what you want.

- `df1$name %in% df2$name` tests whether the values in `df1$name` are in `df2$name`
- The `!` operator reverses the result.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you have any idea what I should do to make it symmetric? I noticed that `df1[!(df1$name %in% df2$name),]` and `df2[!(df2$name %in% df1$name),]` give me different results...

Comment: This helped me a lot just now. Not sure if I could've found the `%in%` operator. It's not really a searchable thing..

Comment: If I would does not remove but modify for NA how could I do that?

Answer (score 44):

This is sometimes called an **anti-join**:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(df1, df2, by = "name")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df1[!(as.character(df1$jobId) %in% as.character(df2$name)), ]
```

I had to add `as.character` to my execution because `name` is not a character but a factor instead. Isn't `%in%` supposed to convert this directly?