# Drop rows with true values from another dataframe

Tags: r

I've this issue, with R,

I've 2 dataframes

```
df1
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ col1        : num  75 90 20 25 90
 $ col3        : num  8.66 9.49 4.47 5 9.49 

df2
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ obs       : int  1 2 3 4 5 
 $ lever     : num  0.00816 0.0113 0.32403 0.21911 0.0113
```

I need to delete from df1 all values which lever in df2 are greater than 0.1
which is equivalent to 3rd and 4th values of obs in df2 right?

I should get a new dataframe df3 kind of

```
df3
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ col1        : num  75 90  90 
 $ col3        : num  8.66 9.49 9.49
```

I've check this link

[Delete rows that exist in another data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17338411/delete-rows-that-exist-in-another-data-frame)

But it's not exactly the right solution.

Thank you if you can help

Comment: I see, that's to me, my mistake, correction done. not 141, but 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `subset`.  Assuming that we are comparing corresponding rows of the equal dimension datasets, use the logical expression (`df2$lever <= 0.1`) to subset the rows of the first dataset

```
df3 <- subset(df1, df2$lever  <= 0.1)
df3
#  col1 col3
#1   75 8.66
#2   90 9.49
#5   90 9.49
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 =c(75, 90, 20, 25, 90), col3 = c(8.66, 9.49, 4.47, 5, 9.49))
df2 <- data.frame(obs = 1:5, lever = c(0.00816, 0.0133, 0.32403, 0.21911, 0.0113))
```

Comment: Thank you man, you're great.

Comment: @CarlosCarvalho  Glad to be of help for you